# How to display double without exponential format in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, double, qstring

Here is a random double number:0.123456e+13

I wanna display without exponential like this "0.123456"

```
QString s = "0.123456e+13";
double d = s.toDouble();
qDebug() << d;  //0.123456e+13

//I try this solution that I search on the internet but it didn't work
double d2 = QStirng::number(d,'g',6).toDouble();
qDebug() << d2; //0.123456e+13
```

0.123456e+13->0.123456
display in qt

Comment: Uh, those two numbers are *very* different. Are you sure you want to mis-represent your number?

Comment: yeah I'm pretty sure cause I don't need the digit too long

Comment: The "e" is not decoration, it means "multiply by this power of 10"

Comment: `double d2 = QStirng::number(d,'g',6).toDouble();` this attempted trick can't possibly work because a `double` does not store any type of information on how to display itself. As a programmer you need to handle the desired visualization in your code. This calculator may help you understand what your computing device holds in memory to represent a `float` variable: [https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/](https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/) see the `Binary:` row. That is what is stored for a 32 bit float.

Comment: thanks for answering me it's really helpful, It's so embarrassing that I think I comprehend the wrong way what 'e' means

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to display `0.123456e+13` as `1234560000000`, not `0.123456`, then you can use `Qt::fixed`(just like how you would use `std::fixed`):

```cpp
qDebug() << Qt::fixed << d;
```